# How can I correct this in the visual studio 2010 theme?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have recently moved to a dark color theme for all my code editors. It is much easier on the eyes. But I recently came across an issue that I can’t figure out how to correct and was hoping that someone will have an answer.

When the method info box pops up this is what it looks like this:

[image: vs2010]

Notice the method info is unreadable because the colors in the theme are meant for a dark background. How can I change the background of this popup?

The theme is a modified version of [Coding Instinct](http://studiostyles.info/schemes/coding-instinct-theme) available on [StudioStyles](http://studiostyles.info/). [Here](http://cid-11d05b676a3170c4.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/VSSettings/coding-instinct-theme-2010.vssettings) is my modified version. It sets the background for the linenumbers/marker margin plus some other minor tweaks.

Comment: This seems to be the Achilles' heel of most themeable IDEs; Eclipse has this problem too

Comment: @Ryan Could you please post a link to the theme. (settings file export) A) because it looks nice and I'd like to try it. B) To help find a solution to the problem

Comment: @ondesertverge I updated the original post with the link to the theme. I included the original plus the one that I tweaked as some things were incompatible with the dark background.

Comment: @Ryan thanks. I installed both the original and you updated theme and the menu shows fine by me for both. Maybe the problem is not the theme.

Comment: @ondesertverge hmmm - thats weird then. the only colors I changed where in the "font/colors" section. Haven't even looked at the Theme Editor until some mentioned it here.

Comment: @Ryan The color of your active tab is also different than on my system. Try looking into your **Windows** theme settings...

Comment: ive disabled all my extensions i have to see if that makes any difference, and it did. one of the extensions add syntax coloring to the info popup. now i just have to figure out which one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) extension causing the issue. Someone on the Q&A discussion thread for [Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) said:

> it seems that the Fonts and Colors selection for "Signature Help Tooltip Background" is the Text Editor color definition that effects this.